# Redux mapDispatchToProps not getting proper payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So there is this simplified structure in my app:

In component i have :

```
   handlePageClick(data) {
        this.props.onChangePage(data.selected + 1);
        this.props.onSearchSomething(this.props.PM);
    }
```

In my Container :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onUpdateForm: (propPath, val) => {
        dispatch(updatePMForm(propPath, val));
    },
    onSearchSomething: (payload) => {
        // TODO: process the PM state here when integrating with the server in order to extract
        // the proper payload out of the state object
        dispatch(searchSomething(15, payload));
    },
    onChangePage: (pageNumber) => {
        dispatch(changePage(pageNumber));
    },
});
```

So when i trigger pageClick, and onChangePage returns newState, in mapDispatchToProps dispatch(searchSomething(15, payload)) receive previous State in payload, that hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: you should try to debug your code... if on debugger it works then use `setTimeout` for some miliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillUpdate` and diff previous state with current one and then call `this.props.onSearchSomething` with updated value from the store rather than call it one after another in `handlePageClick`. Why is that? State changes in a component are potentially asynchronous and almost in all cases there's no way that the component's props will be updated between `this.props.onChangePage` and `this.props.onSearchSomething` calls. Please read [this issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291#issuecomment-185706321) for better understanding what I'm talking about.

But to help you out a bit some time ago I created a small utility [map-props-changes-to-callbacks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-props-changes-to-callbacks) to assign callbacks in your components to specific changes in redux store. Perhaps that can be helpful in your case and you can write your code like that:

```
handlePageClick(data) {
  this.props.onChangePage(data.selected + 1)
}

onPageChanged() {
  this.props.onSearchSomething(this.props.PM)
}
```

Also, you should consider moving your logic to a single action so you can just dispatch one action and get the search result in return.

Comment: onChangePage is a simple action that sends to reducer a new pageValue from pagination, and then when newState is created, then should fire async function searchSomething(15, payload). in debbug i see in mapStateToProps a new state, but the payload is still previous state.